# jQuery element works with append() but not after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, jquery-after

I am modifying a script to display a warning on password fields if CAPS lock is on.

The element that I am building is added to the page just fine if I use the `append()` method but that's not very extensible as it would rely on the password field having a relevant parent element. What I want to do is add it `after()` the password field but when I do it is displayed as `[object Object]`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":password").bind("keypress", function(e) {
    el = jQuery('<div/>', {
      id: 'caps_warning',
      text: 'CAPS lock is on'
    })

    kc = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    sk = e.shiftKey ? e.shiftKey : ((kc == 16) ? true : false);

    if(((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk) || ((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk)) {
      el.appendTo(e.currentTarget.parentElement);
    } else {
    }
  });
});
```

I want to replace `el.appendTo(e.currentTarget.parentElement);` with `e.currentTarget.after(el);`.

Comment: Try using `$(e.currentTarget).after(el)`

Comment: Offtopic: that empty else really annoys me

Comment: "_I use the append() method but that's not very extensible as it would **rely on the password field having a relevant parent element**._"  [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) adds the passed content as a child and not as a sibling to every element of the collection. The `:password` thing would be the parent element of `el`

Comment: Sorry @CarlosCarucce, it's a work in progress!

Comment: @Andreas yeah I think that's the point I was trying to make, I need it as a sibling and not a child

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`e.currentTarget` is a dom node, not a jQuery object. It is also the same as `this`

Try

```
$(this).after(el)
```